# arg.parse для gunicorn на flask+heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, gunicorn, argparse

Суть проблемы: имеется чат-приложение, запускающееся на heroku. Для запуска приложения всегда нужно проставлять аргументы в командной строке вроде `--login-token blablabla --chat-host blablabla --chat-port blablabla`.

На `heroku` же используется `gunicorn`, который, судя по всему, не пропускает эти аргументы. По крайней мере, в самом `py`-файле приложения они установлены по умолчанию, когда я начинаю "устанавливать" (deploy) приложение на `heroku`, `gunicorn` выдает ошибку того, что не распознает аргументы и ругается на них.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то другие варианты, чтобы провести аргументы в `gunicorn`? Проблема относится специфически именно к зеленому единорогу...